# Sublime Text: Larger tab sizes?

Tags: editor, sublimetext3

For assembly sources, it is sometimes useful to use tab and indentation settings larger than the default maximum of 8. I'd like to have that at 10.

Is this possible with sublime, and if yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can set `"tab_size": 10,` in your syntax specific settings.

Open an assembly file, then the Preferences menu -> Settings - Syntax Specific and add the preference in the pane on the right hand side, and save.

Now, pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> will insert 10 spaces, and the indent guides will also be lined up every 10 spaces.

You may wish to also set `"detect_indentation": false,` in the preferences to ensure that Sublime Text uses this tab size for all assembly sources.